# Upload Images from desktop via Ckeditor

Tags: php, image, file-upload, ckeditor, fckeditor

I am using `Bonfire` library of `Codeigniter`, I have to configure a `CKeditor` with the `browse` option right from my desktop computer.

I have searched alot and find `server browse` which is unfortunately useless for me as I want to upload the images from computer, `Fckeditor,DOKSoft` and many more are the examples but I am unable to get the most compatible one for me.

Comment: What is the question???

Answer (score 0):

Use CKFinder plugin for CKEditor. That will allow you to upload images.